# Bounced email handlers PHP

Tags: php, handler, email-bounces

i am building an email system and i'd like to receive a bounce notification if the email bounces and display it in the dashboard. Any ideas on how to acheve this? any email functions i am not aware of? Best

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not the right place where to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025424/how-to-write-a-php-script-that-read-bounce-email

Comment: PHP can not handle this on its own; first of all you would need to configure the local MTA to “forward” such incoming mails to PHP, before it can do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your mail server to capture all bounced emails, for example calling a script on your server which could handle them as you want.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script) for a possible resolution in Postfix.

Feel free to add more details and I can clarify my answer more.